# javax.mail separating email threads

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a java application that monitors an inbox and reads new messages. I only want the latest message in a thread read, however when an email with multiple replies in the same thread is parsed, it reads the whole thing.

Is it possible to read only the latest reply in an email thread using javax.mail? Or would I need to place some logic to look at the header and determine the latest by comparing the send date?

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate messages in your mailbox for each reply, you have to decide how to determine that they're part of the same "thread".  There's no perfect way to do this and different mailers will do it differently.  A good start is the References and In-Reply-To headers.  Once you know the set of messages that are part of a single thread, you can choose the latest one by date.

If you have a single message that includes the text of previous replies in the body of the message and you want to separate the latest reply from the previous replies, you'll have to process the text in the body and decide which parts are previous replies and which part is the current reply.  Again, there is no perfect solution and this will require more heuristics.